# How to paginate through api?

Tags: api, dash

I have looked at the following link:https://dashblockexplorer.com/api/txs/?block=990001, and I am wondering how to paginate. You may notice that `pageTotal` is equal to 5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

From its [api info page](https://dashblockexplorer.com/api-info), *dashblockexplorer.com* uses [insigth api](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api), and so just append to the url:

> &pageNum=#

For example, for the next page (#1, as it starts on zero):

> https://dashblockexplorer.com/api/txs/?block=990001&pageNum=1

Last page should be **pageNum** = **pagesTotal-1**